# How to Show Loading Animation In Polymer

Tags: ajax, polymer, loading, polymer-2.x

I am trying to show a loading spinner while iron-ajax is loading, otherwise, show the AJAX content.  However, I can only get the DOM to display one or the other based on the `!` before the loading property.

```js
Polymer({
  is: 'example-element',
  connectedCallback() {
    console.log(this.loading); // logs undefined
  }
});
```

```html
<base href="https://polygit.org/polymer+polymer+v2.5.0/components/" />
<script src="webcomponentsjs/webcomponents-lite.js"></script>
<link rel="import" href="polymer/polymer.html" />
<link rel="import" href="iron-ajax/iron-ajax.html" />
<link rel="import" href="paper-spinner/paper-spinner.html" />

<example-element></example-element>

<dom-module id="example-element">
  <iron-ajax id="ajax" url="https://api/endpoint" method="post" handle-as="json" content-type="application/json" body="[[request]]" last-response="{{response}}" loading="{{loading}}"></iron-ajax>

  <template is="dom-if" if="{{loading}}">
      <paper-spinner active></paper-spinner>
    </template>

  <template is="dom-if" if="{{!loading}}">
      <template is="dom-repeat" items="[[response]]" as="item">
        <p>[[item]]</p>
      </template>
  </template>
</dom-module>
```

Does the loading property need to be explicitly set in the components properties?

Answer (score 2):

In your example, you're not actually telling `iron-ajax` to do anything, so it won't.

Until it does something `loading` will be undefined you can print out the contents of loading so you can see what state it's in.

I've put together an example that will show you the state but also has a button so you can trigger `iron-ajax` to do a request (I suggest using chrome for the example).

```js
Polymer({
  is: 'example-element',
  _startRequest: function() {
    this.shadowRoot.querySelector('iron-ajax').generateRequest()
  }
});
```

```html
<base href="https://polygit.org/polymer+polymer+v2.5.0/components/" />
<script src="webcomponentsjs/webcomponents-lite.js"></script>
<link rel="import" href="polymer/polymer.html" />
<link rel="import" href="iron-ajax/iron-ajax.html" />
<link rel="import" href="paper-spinner/paper-spinner.html" />
<link rel="import" href="paper-button/paper-button.html" />

<example-element></example-element>

<dom-module id="example-element">
  <template>
    <div>Loading status:[[loading]]</div>
    <iron-ajax id="ajax"
      url="https://api/endpoint"
      method="post"
      handle-as="json"
      content-type="application/json"
      body="[[request]]"
      last-response="{{response}}"
      loading="{{loading}}"></iron-ajax>

    <template is="dom-if" if="{{loading}}">
      <paper-spinner active></paper-spinner>
    </template>

  <template is="dom-if" if="{{!loading}}">
      I appear when loading is false
  </template>

  <br />
  <paper-button on-tap="_startRequest">Load</paper-button>
  </template>
</dom-module>
```

I hope you find this helpful

Comment: In the actual code I have an observer that automatically runs the AJAX call when another property is changed.  So the AJAX call is running and pulling data from the database...

Comment: Did you read the rest of the answer? Printing loading out into your page may help you work out the issue.